# return none duplicated mysql row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a table with two columns `begin_timestamp` and `images`.

First I do this statement

```
SELECT images 
FROM myTable 
WHERE begin_timestamp < 1546646400 && images != 'default.png';
```

This will return me a list of strings like :

```
'123.jpg'
'abc.jpg'
'test.jpg'
```

What I want as second is to check if one or more items of that list has a duplication in the hole table. If yes, kick that string out of the list. Like if a other row in the table contains `123.jpg` as image value I just want the list like

```
[abc.jpg, test.jpg]
```

My question is now, how can I combine the first and the second step to one  mySQL statement?

Comment: what is the datatype of `images` column?

Comment: you could probably simply make use of `DISTINCT`

Comment: Do you want to check for duplicates in the table without the `where` clause? Or do you only want to check for duplicates within the result set?

Comment: I want to check for duplicates in the table without the where clause

Comment: Do you also need to query other fields of the row? or only `images`?

Comment: @Felk only images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using `GROUP BY`.

First, let's do the selection as above:

```
SELECT images
FROM myTable
WHERE begin_timestamp < 1546646400 AND images != 'default.png'
GROUP BY images;
```

now, because we have grouped by `images`, we have access to [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html). We can add the desired filter like this at the end of the query:

```
HAVING COUNT(images) = 1
```

Note that because we have grouped by `images`, that now is the only thing we can directly query in the `SELECT` part. If you want to select any other fields, you need to do so through an aggregate function as well, e.g. `SELECT images, MIN(some_field)`. Or if `images` is the primary key, use it in a subquery or join.

---

If you need to remove duplicates *before* applying the `WHERE` filter condition, you can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT images FROM (
    SELECT images, MIN(begin_timestamp) as begin_timestamp
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY images
    HAVING COUNT(images) = 1)
WHERE begin_timestamp < 1546646400 AND images != 'default.png';
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. This filter my list like `[123.jpg, 123. jpg, abc.jpg, test.jpg]` to `[abc.jpg, test.jpg]` But I want to check over the hole table. Like if this are the only two entry with `123.jpg` and there is no other entry with 123.jpg in the hole table I want to keep them in that list. If there a other entry with 123.jpg somewhere in the table but not in that list I want to kick that two out of the list

Comment: Hade to edit it like this for no sql syntax error: `SELECT images FROM (
    SELECT images, begin_timestamp
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY images, begin_timestamp
    HAVING COUNT(images) = 1) AS InnerStatement
WHERE begin_timestamp < 1546646400 AND images != 'default.png';` But I still get results which has duplications in the table outside of the where clausel

Comment: yeah, I forgot `begin_timestamp` isn't available due to the `group by` I think I fixed it in my ansert, but going with Omar Matijas' answer is probably easier for your case anyway

Answer (score 2):

Other way to do it is with NOT EXISTS.

I assumed you have and id field in the table:

```
SELECT images 
FROM myTable m1
where m1.begin_timestamp < 1546646400 && m1.images != 'default.png'
and NOT EXISTS(select 1 from myTable m2 where m1.images = m2.images and m1.id != m2.id)
```

Comment: compared to the `GROUP BY` solution, this has the advantage that you can select all fields, not just `images`.

Answer (score 0):

declare @image varchar(max)
set @image=''

SELECT @image=@image+','+ images 
FROM myTable 
WHERE begin_timestamp < 1546646400 AND images != 'default.png'
GROUP BY images
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

select @image